# Evaluating an expression in the head of the clause

Tags: prolog

Is there any way to evaluate this sum inside the `findall/3` clause?

```
findall((A+C,[M,H|_]),(b_to_b(H,M,C),\+ member(M,[H|T])),R).
```

Here i get values like `(1+3,List)` and i'm looking for some shortcut so that i get value `4` instead of `(1+3)`

I understand what is the problem but a shortcut will be nice otherwise i have to revisit the whole list and that's not nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming A has already been binded to a numeric, just move the evaluation from the template to the goal:

```
...,
findall((S,[M,H|_]),(b_to_b(H,M,C),\+ member(M,[H|T]), S is A+C),R).
```

Efficiency hint: you should also change member/2 to memberchk/2.